# Rest Client with AndroidAnnotations - "no suitable HttpMessageConverter..."

Tags: android, gson, resttemplate, android-annotations

I want to send POST request to server. I have to pass JSON object as a parameter, and get JSON as a response, but I am getting this error:

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [com.package.Response] and content type [application/octet-stream]
```

Code

Sending request:

```
    @RestService
    RestClient restClient;
...
    String json = "{\"param\":3}"; 
    restClient.getRestTemplate().getMessageConverters().add(new GsonHttpMessageConverter());
    Response res = restClient.send(json);
```

RestClient

```
@Rest("http://my-url.com")

    public interface RestClient
    {
        @Post("/something/")
        Response send(String json);

        RestTemplate getRestTemplate();

        void setRestTemplate(RestTemplate restTemplate);
    }
```

I'm using these JAR files:

- spring-android-rest-template-1.0.0.RC1
- spring-android-core-1.0.0.RC1
- spring-android-auth-1.0.0.RC1
- gson-2.2.2

What I'm doing wrong? 
When I change `send` parameter to `JSONObject` I am getting the same error. 
Btw. AA docs are really enigmatic - can I use Gson anyway? 
 Or should I use Jackson? 
Which file do I need to include then? 


Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use RestTemplate with either Gson or Jackson.

Gson is fine and easier to use of you have small json data set. Jackson is more suitable if you have a complex / deep json tree, because Gson creates a lot of temporary objects which leads to stop the world GCs.

The error here says that it cannot find a `HttpMessageConverter` able to parse `application/octet-stream`.

If you look at the sources for [GsonHttpMessageConverter](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org%24maven2@org.springframework.android%24spring-android-rest-template@1.0.0.RELEASE@org%24springframework%24http%24converter%24json%24GsonHttpMessageConverter.java), you'll notice that it only supports the mimetype `application/json`.

This means you have two options :

- Either return the `application/json` mimetype from your content, which would seam quite appropriate
- Or just change the supported media types on `GsonHttpMessageConverter` :

```java
String json = "{\"param\":3}"; 
GsonHttpMessageConverter converter = new GsonHttpMessageConverter();
converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(new MediaType("application", "octet-stream", Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
restClient.getRestTemplate().getMessageConverters().add(converter);
Response res = restClient.send(json);
```

Comment: Thanks you very much! Will new version of AA support annotations for HttpMessageConverters?

Comment: Yep, that's part of the plan :)

Comment: Cool, thanks Piwaï.

Just a bit more info in case others need it: to add this, I ditched the auto-generated-from-interface RestClient and used the generated class as the basis - then added Piwaï's code above to the constructor. Except for me, setSupportedMediaTypes takes a List of MediaTypes so I added the MediaType to a List first.

You can then switch \@RestClient for \@EBean and reference your class with \@Bean. 

Worked for me anyway! :)

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem. After several hours I realised that the class I was passing in to the RestTemplate.postForObject call had Date variables. You need to make sure it only contains simple data types. Hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

I have to modify it little to work:

```
final List<MediaType> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.addAll(converter.getSupportedMediaTypes());
list.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(list);
```